# how to change the out_features of densenet121 model?

Tags: python, pytorch, densenet

How to change the `out_features` of `densenet121` model?

I am using the code below to train the model:

```py
from torch.nn.modules.dropout import Dropout
    
class Densnet121(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Densnet121, self).__init__() 
        self.cnn1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3 , out_channels=64 , kernel_size=3 , stride=1 )
        self.Densenet_121 = models.densenet121(pretrained=True)
        self.gap = AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(1024)
        self.do1 = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(256,256)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)
        self.do2 = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        self.output = nn.Linear(64 * 64 * 64,2)
        self.act = nn.ReLU()
        
    def densenet(self):
        for param in self.Densenet_121.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
        self.Densenet_121.classifier = nn.Linear(1024, 1024)
        return self.Densenet_121
    
    def forward(self, x):
        img = self.act(self.cnn1(x))
        img = self.densenet(img)      
    
        img = self.gap(img)
        img = self.bn1(img)
        img = self.do1(img)
        img = self.linear(img)
        img = self.bn2(img)
        img = self.do2(img)
        img = torch.flatten(img, 1)
        img = self.output(img)
    
        return img
```

When training this model, I face the following error:

> ```
> RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 7, 7], expected input[64, 64, 62, 62] to have 3 channels, but got 64 channels instead
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first conv layer outputs a tensor of shape `(b, 64, h, w)` while the following layer, the densenet model expects 3 channels. Hence the error that was raised:

> "expected input [...] to have **3 channels**, but got **64 channels instead**"

Unfortunately, this value is hardcoded in the source of the Densenet class, see [reference](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/densenet.py#L170).

One workaround however is to overwrite the first convolutional layer after the densenet has been initialized. Something like this should work:

```
# First gather the conv layer specs
conv = self.Densenet_121.features.conv0
kwargs = {k: getattr(conv, k) for k in 
   ('out_channels', 'stride', 'kernel_size', 'padding', 'bias')}

# overwrite with identical specs with new in_channels
model.features.conv0 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, **kwargs)
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
w = model.features.conv0.weight
w.data = torch.rand(len(w), 64, *w.shape[:2])
```

Which replaces the underlying convolutional layer weight without affecting its metadata (eg. `conv.in_channels` remains equal to `3`), this could have side effects. So I would recommend following the first approach.